# find the row with the largest sum in a matrix dynamic programming

Tags: matrix, dynamic-programming

i have a matrix and I have to find the row with the largest  sum. The algorithm should use dynamic programming.

4 **5** 3 2 1
2 2 **7** 2 5
1 **4** 2 5 6
**9** 1 2 1 6

The numbers need to be directly or diagonally connected.
My idea was to search the largest number in every line and check if it is directly or diagonally connected to the largest number of the next line. If not I go back, take the next smaller number and check again. But i notice that my idea is not use dynamic programming. This was my only idea.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: the thing is, you can save a lot of calculations, if you save the subtrees. for  example after choosing(5 7 4 9) you try (4 2 4 9) so the last (4 9) are same.

Answer (score 0):

I am mentioning this dp approach but it can be further optimized:

Let given array be:

```
a11 ... a1n
.
.
. 
am1 ... amn
```

and solution be:

```
s11 ... s1n
.
.
. 
sm1 ... smn
```

You may start with first row and find soln. for each element in that row. This is your trivial case and ans will be same as row 1.

```
s11 = a11
..
s1n = a1n
```

Now row 2.

```
s21 = max(s11, s12) + a21;
s22 = max(s11, s12, s13) + a22;
s23 = max(s12, s13, s14) + a23;
.
.
```

Now in general:

```
s[m][n] = max(s[m-1][n-1], s[m-1][n], s[m-1][n+1]) + a[m][n];
```

Idea is to keep track of ans that ends on a particular element a[x][y]. Now it can only be reached from a[x-1][y-1] or a[x-1][y] or a[x-1][y+1].